# How to run a batch (.bat) file on Ubuntu using Wine (with complete steps)?

Tags: wine, games, batch

I have this old Windows game with a .bat file which doesn't open with Wine and only opens as a text file. I have browsed through and tried several suggested ways of opening it with Wine console without any success. Many other methods are either too complex or coded for a layman like me to understand. So, can someone please provide a simple step-by-step guidance on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

## The solution by OP

1. Install Wine & configure it to relevant Windows version for game
2. Open Gedit (notepad of Ubuntu)>Edit>Preferences>Plugins>select 'External tools execute external commands shell scripts'>Close
3. Go to your .bat file>right click>Properties>Permissions>select 'allow executing file as program'>Close
4. Double-click the .bat file, it will open in gedit>Tools>External Tools>Run command>in the popped up box type 'wineconsole cmd' (without inverted commas)>OK. 5. A Wine console terminal will pop up, in it type 'start yourfilename.bat' and hit enter. That'll run it.

Answer (score 0):

## Easier Yet

having wine installed on your system:

- right click > open with other application
- select Wine Windows Program Loader

Done