# .Bat file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, games

I've been wondering how to start a `.bat` file via terminal? There's this win game that requires me to run the `.bat` first before going in any ideas how?

Comment: Batch (`.bat`) files are for the Windows command environment. I don't think there's any way to run them on Linux.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to run a batch (.bat) file on Ubuntu using Wine (with complete steps)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661113/how-to-run-a-batch-bat-file-on-ubuntu-using-wine-with-complete-steps)

Answer (score 2):

Since the game is for Windows, there is no way to run it on Linux directly; for that you are going to need WINE (Wine Is Not an Emulator) in order to make the game run.

You can [download it from here](https://www.winehq.org/) and find all the information that you need.

Comment: aawwww , well thanks . now i know i can't run bat file O-O''' but any who, i found the solution -- there were a bunch of exe's to initiate the files so i (as you said , Used wine) and it worked now  thank you!